# Removing dictionary items based on specific values having a sub-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, network-programming

I have a dictionary based on output of a command 'show cdp neighbor detail' from a Cisco switch. The dictionary has more than 200 key value pairs. Sample dictionary pairs are as follows.

```
{'device_id': 'Switch-Hostname1', 'ip_address': '1.1.1.1', 'platform': 'Cisco IP Phone', 'capabilities': 'Host Phone Two-port Mac Relay', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/1', 'remote_port': 'Port 1'}
{'device_id': 'Phone-Hostname2', 'ip_address': '2.2.2.2', 'platform': 'WS-C3750', 'capabilities': 'Switch IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/2', 'remote_port': 'FastEthernet1/0/48'}
{'device_id': 'AccessPoint-Hostname3', 'ip_address': '3.3.3.3', 'platform': 'AIR-CAP3700-K9', 'capabilities': 'Trans-Bridge Source-Route-Bridge IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/3', 'remote_port': 'GigabitEthernet0'}
```

I need to remove the dictionary items based on the values of the dictionary key 'platform'. The corresponding values of key 'platform' should not contain the sub-string "AIR-" as mention in the third entry in the sample code above.

Please advise how can I achieve this, I'm using Python 3.

**EDIT**
Actually I want to remove the dictionaries having the sub-string "AIR-" in the values of key 'platform'.
And, after this first filtering, from the remaining dictionaries, I want to retrieve the values of 'local_port' preferably in a list.

Comment: How you're storing `dictionary` in a `list` or any `file`? Can you show your efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, are you asking to remove just the item that contains substring or the whole dictionary if the specific value has a substring?

In the first case you can use dict comprehensions as follows:

```
orig = {'device_id': 'AccessPoint-Hostname3', 'ip_address': '3.3.3.3', 'platform': 'AIR-CAP3700-K9', 'capabilities': 'Trans-Bridge Source-Route-Bridge IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/3', 'remote_port': 'GigabitEthernet0'}
new = {k: v for k, v in orig.items() if substr not in v}
```

In the second case you can use list comprehension:

```
info_old = [{'device_id': 'Switch-Hostname1', 'ip_address': '1.1.1.1', 'platform': 'Cisco IP Phone', 'capabilities': 'Host Phone Two-port Mac Relay', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/1', 'remote_port': 'Port 1'},
            {'device_id': 'Phone-Hostname2', 'ip_address': '2.2.2.2', 'platform': 'WS-C3750', 'capabilities': 'Switch IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/2', 'remote_port': 'FastEthernet1/0/48'},
            {'device_id': 'AccessPoint-Hostname3', 'ip_address': '3.3.3.3', 'platform': 'AIR- CAP3700-K9', 'capabilities': 'Trans-Bridge Source-Route-Bridge IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/3', 'remote_port': 'GigabitEthernet0'}]

info_new = [r for r in info_old if not substr in r[field]]
```

Where `substr` is the string you'd like to avoid (`"AIR-"`)and `field` is the field you are looking in (`"platform"` in your case)

**EDIT:**
The question was edited to make it a bit clearer now. For the first part the given solution should work as expected:

```
info_new = [r for r in info_old if not substr in r[unwanted_field]]
```

For the second part you could do another list comprehension:

```
ports = [r[wanted_field] for r in info_new]
```

Or, if you don't need the list of cleaned dictionaries for anything else, you could merge this into a single comprehension as follows:

```
ports = [r[wanted_field] for r in info_old if not substr in r[unwanted_field]]
```

where `info_old` is a list of original dictionaries, `substr` the part you want to parse out (`"AIR-"`), `wanted_field` the name of the field with the value you want to isolate (`"local_port"`) and `unwanted_field` the name of the field you want to search for the `substr` (`"platform"`)

Comment: I want to achieve the second case actually, "remove whole dictionary if the specific value has a sub-string". Sorry if the original question was bit unclear. Let me try the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the best option is to work with a DataFrame. In your dictionaries, you have the same keys for item. So you can change to a dataframe in a simple way and it allows you to go into the data easily:

```
import pandas as pd

dic1 = {'device_id': 'Switch-Hostname1', 'ip_address': '1.1.1.1', 'platform': 'Cisco IP Phone', 'capabilities': 'Host Phone Two-port Mac Relay', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/1', 'remote_port': 'Port 1'}
dic2 = {'device_id': 'Phone-Hostname2', 'ip_address': '2.2.2.2', 'platform': 'WS-C3750', 'capabilities': 'Switch IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/2', 'remote_port': 'FastEthernet1/0/48'}
dic3 = {'device_id': 'AccessPoint-Hostname3', 'ip_address': '3.3.3.3', 'platform': 'AIR-CAP3700-K9', 'capabilities': 'Trans-Bridge Source-Route-Bridge IGMP', 'local_port': 'GigabitEthernet1/3', 'remote_port': 'GigabitEthernet0'}`

data = pd.DataFrame([dic1, dic2, dic3]);
data = data[data['platform'].str.contains("AIR") != True]
```